# pipe image request coming from frontend in nodejs with custom headers

Tags: node.js, node-request

I need to pipe the image request coming from frontend to another url in nodejs with custom headers. I have a code which already works for the same without headers.

html:

```
<form id="ImageForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/image/test" name="image-test-form">
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Using [express](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html) and [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)  (this code works fine) :

```
app.post( '/image/test', (req, res, next) => {
  var url = "http://www.somedomain.com/image/test";
  var headers = {'h1': 'test', 'h2': 'header'}; // TODO: send headers
  req.pipe(request.post (url,req.body)).pipe(res)
  .on('error', function(err) { res.status(500).send(err);});
});
```

I couldn't figure out how to pass headers along the request. Tried to use formData and form in request, not working.

Comment: What about setting `req.headers.h1` and `req.headers.h2` before piping?

Comment: @robertklep Thanks man! That worked like charm.

Comment: I'll write it up as an answer. I wasn't sure it was going to work, hence initially a comment ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before piping, you can add your custom headers to `req.headers`:

```
req.headers.h1 = 'test';
req.headers.h2 = 'header';

req.pipe(request.post (url,req.body)).pipe(res)
```